# selenium 2 and junit

Tags: junit, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Do most people use there selenium (in my case selenium 2 with web driver) tests with JUnit?  I personally do not and was wondering if I am in the minority.  I tend to write all my own classes and exception handling and have everything write to a database for reporting on results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a testing framework but feel like JUnit is too restrictive, you might want to consider using TestNG.  It is designed for integration testing and has features that make GUI automation easier.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see with your approach is that the more code you write yourself instead of relying on existing third party libraries, the more maintenance you will have.

If you have the option of using third party, your should (in most cases) integrate it instead of writing something yourself.

Comment: I guess I just like my GUI automation to be more robust using page or domain design patterns to map the site under test to code.  I see JUnit as a unit test framework and do not look at GUI automation in that light

Answer (score 0):

At the end it comes to your personal choice,if your test code is small and easier to maintain and keep track of.
For enterprise-level web application having multiple modules to be automated,we have to choose some sort of test framework for easier automation and reporting purposes.
I personally prefer TestNG as it is code is clutter free and more readable.Cheers!